# How do I disable Mouse Wheel zoom functionality in ArcGIS Silverlight?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I have an ArcGIS Silverlight app with a Map object.  It containes an ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer and a GraphicsLayer. We've written a custom measure tool for adding in a point at an offset on the graphic layer.  I am trying to disable the mouse wheel zoom-in/zoom-out function when this tool is activated to prevent the user from being able to zooom while performing a measurement.

I've played around with various combinations of setting the map.IsHitTestVisible = false, graphicLayer.IsHitTestVisible = false, overriding OnMouseWheel(), all with no sucess.  It either had no effect, or it disabled ALL mouse events, including the mouse down and mouse move event which I need for the measure tool.

I've read thru the documentation on the MouseWheel but I guess I'm not understanding it correctly. I just can't seem to get it to do what I want.  And I can't find any specific examples that do what I want either.

Any suggestions or places I can look to figure this out?

I am using Silverlight 4 and ESRI Silverlight 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you could try setting the Map's `ZoomFactor` property to <strike>zero</strike> `1` (storing the old value) while your measurement tool is active.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map~ZoomFactor.html

Comment: Or maybe zoomfactor = 1.

Comment: Thank you both!! I forgot to put in my original question that I had tried setting zoom factor to 0 but it didn't quite work the way I wanted.  But setting it to 1 did.  Problem solved!!